# SQL cx in syntax, what does it means

Tags: sql, syntax

I have sql syntax something like this

```
WITH cx (Policy_Number,Claim_Incurred)

  AS (

    SELECT PolicyNo

      ,SUM(ReservedAmt + PaidAmt - SalvageAmt + ReservedExp + PaidExp - SalvageExp)

    FROM eInsurance.dbo.Claim

    GROUP BY PolicyNo

  )
```

or something like this

```
REFERENCE.dbo.FXRate fx
    JOIN eInsurance.dbo.PolicyM pm
      ON fx.currency = pm.PRCurrency
    LEFT JOIN cx
      ON pm.PolicyNo = cx.Policy_Number
    JOIN eInsurance.dbo.Account acc
      ON pm.AccCode = acc.AccCode
    JOIN eInsurance.dbo.AccTypeList atl
      ON acc.AccType = atl.TypeCode
```

So what does cx means in its syntax..?

Comment: That's referred to as a `common table expression`.  Basically it's like a subquery that can be reference in the subsequent query.  So `cx` is the alias for the query it contains.

Answer (score 1):

`cx` is called a common table expression, usually referred to as a CTE.

You can think of it as a temporary view on the data, defined only for a single query.  You could replace the `cx` with the definition in the `with` clause.